# android String LatLng(75.7403, 72.44697) перевести location

Tags: android

android String LatLng(75.7403, 72.44697) перевести location. она приходит как стока, мне дано получить lat и lng в double

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String replace = data.replace("LatLng(", "").replace(", ", ",").replace(")", "");

```
    String[] strArray = new String[0];
    strArray = replace.split(",");
    Double.valueOf(strArray[0])
    Double.valueOf(strArray[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы об этом?

```
  LatLng loc = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
  Location location = new Location("my location");
  location.setLatitude(loc.latitude);
  location.setLongitude(loc.longitude);
```